# Why has my Azure Data Factory Dataflow stopped moving files to the archive folder when completed

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a number of pipelines that call dataflows and in each one I've configured the "After completion" to move the files to an archive folder. For roughly half the pipelines this works, but the other half doesn't move the files.

[image]

I've tried changing the From and To fields from parameters to string values and nothing works.
The pipelines all make use of the same runtime and various other configurations so I can't see why some work and some don't.

**Edit:**
Example of working paths.
From: `ebu-con/logistics/as/atg`
To: `ebu-con/logistics/archived/as/atg`

Example of paths that are not working.
From: `ebu-con/logistics/as/orders`
To: `ebu-con/logistics/archived/as/orders`

They're based in the same storage container and folder structure with the exception of the deepest folder, e.g. atg vs orders.

Comment: Can you provide the above sample paths when its working and also paths when its not working as well?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula I've added the paths as requested. The ATG folder works, but Orders doesn't even though it did about a week ago and looking at the pipeline/dataflow history not much has changed and nothing that would suggest it could break the "move" after completion.